# Passive of "show off"

Tags: phrasal-verbs

I came across this sentence in a novel:

> I wonder if she had been the same as me, always being showed off by that genius...

Usually the phrasal verb "show off" is used in active voice, so I was wondering if the passive voice of it also conveys the same meaning.

(the "show off" in this context means "boast").

Thanks for your opinions!

Comment: The passive would be _shown_., not _showed_.

Comment: @KateBunting: I'm not so sure. Consider how we use the "non-standard" past tense *As a boy he **shined** shoes for pocket money*, because the context & meaning is significantly different to, say, *The sun **shone** brightly*. Not exactly the same, but I think maybe it's relevant.

Comment: ...we don't have the full context, but I can't help wondering if maybe the phrasal verb should be ***show up*** (humiliate, belittle) rather than ***show off*** (flaunt, proudly / boastfully exhibit).

Comment: Are you trying to say that the genius boasted to you? What is the effect (on you) that you want to express?

Comment: @ThuanKhang Can you please give the rest of the sentence? I suspect that there might be a typo in it.

Comment: It depends on the context and intended meaning.  Was the speaker, and the woman the speaker was talking about, attractive and being displayed by a boyfriend like some kind of prize?  Or were they the victim of someone showing off and acting superior to them

Comment: I can't understand what your sentence is trying to convey. And it seems that I am not alone in this. Perhaps you could help us out here?

Comment: Is 'this sentence' in fact a complete sentence, as it isn't making any sense as such?

Answer (score 8):

The problem with your sentence is not that you are using *show off* in the passive, but that the subject of the sentence doesn't work with the passive of *show off* because it wouldn't be the object of *show off* if the sentence was in the active voice.

Your sentence is:

> I wonder if she had been the same as me, always being showed off by that genius.

Putting this back into the active case, you get

> that genius was always showing her off,

which would make sense if she was the genius's wife or daughter, and he was boasting about her. However, from context it doesn't seem that this is what you mean.

I am assuming that what you really want to say was

> that genius was always showing off *to her*.

The only way to put this in the passive would be

> always being shown off to by that genius,

which, if it isn't ungrammatical<sup>1</sup>, is at least quite awkward; I would rephrase the original sentence.

<sup>1</sup> Putting verb/preposition pairings into the passive is a complicated topic—sometimes you can do it, and sometimes you can't, and I don't know the rules.

Comment: I think that the intended meaning is “that genius was always showing her off“ - it makes more sense than the alternatives. It is not uncommon - although not politically correct - for men to see a beautiful woman  as a trophy

Answer (score 3):

The use of "showed" is rare ([OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/show_1?q=show), [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?year_end=2008&content=being+showed+off%2Cbeing+shown+off&smoothing=3&corpus=15&year_start=1800&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbeing%20shown%20off%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cbeing%20shown%20off%3B%2Cc0)).

There is no problem with the passive, there are plenty of examples [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22being%20shown%20off%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en).

However, the meaning is not "boast" but "to show people something or somebody that you are proud of".

Comment: One of the definitions of "to show off" is essentially "to boast". [See dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/show-off_1#showoff3_e) "**show off**: *to try to impress others by talking about your abilities, possessions, etc.*" (And as a native English speaker, I can assure you that this definition can be used both transitively and intransitively.)

Comment: @PeterShor The reason is that I have the feeling that "boast" is slightly disapproving. I find this rather confirmed in the definition of "[boast](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/boast_1?q=boast)" since  it reads "to talk in a way that shows you are **too proud** of something that you have or can do".  I don't quite know however, whether the excess is to be imputed to the innocent overestimation of the person boasting or   vaingloriousness from that person, which latter possibility would indicate definitely that the term is disapproving.

Comment: @PeterShor The noun "show off" in American is without doubt disapproving; I've never heard it used differently; as well, the verb "to show off" is very often used with much disdain by Americans; I'm sure of that.

Comment: can you please please not use abbreviations like "sth" on this site, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Without more context, it sounds like the author is describing an implied *victim* of someone "show[ing] off".

If this is the case, a better phrase is to "[show up](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/show%20up)" as FumbleFingers [commented](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/548167/passive-of-show-off#comment1347525_548167) above:

> 2: to embarrass or cause to look bad especially by comparison
>
> trying to show up the boss

Those compared to the show-off would be **shown up**.

Comment: by "victim" do you mean "target"?

Comment: @Charles Yes, I considered that, but it also implies that the show-off did it intentionally and *to* that person, and I'm not a huge fan of ascribing intentions with such little context.  Someone can be a *victim* without the perceived damage being intentional.